# How Do Those With Antisocial Personality Disorder Fair In Solitary Confinement?

Tags: abnormal-psychology

Are there any examples of those with antisocial personality disorder, or people in general, faring relatively well in solitary confinement?

The general consensus seams that solitary confinement is very destructive, but I was wondering if there were any exemptions to this rule?

Comment: I would think that persons with antisocial personality disorder depend on social contacts. But there are persons who fare better in loneliness than others, and those people are for example wanted as astronauts. Maybe you can find some info if you look into what personality is wanted for this or similar jobs (lighthouse keeper, ...).